# Ubuntu 22.04 alsamixer/pulseaudio issues

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I recently started over with a fresh install of Ubuntu (Cinnamon) 22.04, after having some issues with updating to 23.04, as both 22.10 and 23.04 come with pipewire by default, which my sound card does not play nice with.

In the past, I have always had to run a bash script, found [here](https://pastebin.com/6uVzPjCb), in order to have the sound card work properly, with the selected output corresponding with the actual method, but this time the script is not working properly. Currently, in order to have sound come from my laptop speakers I need to have the headphones output selected, and there is no way for my headphones jack to output sound, with either the headphones or standard jack selected.

[image: sound panel]

Simultaneously, the volume increase/decrease is behaving peculiarly, as changing the volume percentage in the configuration GUI in the attached screenshot only has an effect from 0-10%, and any increase beyond that does nothing.

Can anyone suggest something so I can have working headphones and a working volume control? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.04 is a flavor, Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04 was a remix*

Comment: @guiverc alsamixer/pulseaudio is not unique to cinnamon, and instead is common to ALL base/official versions of ubuntu. Things like this, not resolving an on topic question because of a technicality, is why Ubuntu is never going to be taken seriously as a consumer OS.

I've had this exact problem before on Ubuntu/Kubuntu and the bash script I had included had completely fixed it, instead of leaving me with a weird situation where the mic output comes out of the speakers and the speakers themselves don't do anything. Anyways, if you have nothing useful to contribute, don't contribute.